# Google G-Suite Marketplace - No results - can't add Chrome Remote Desktop or any Microsoft apps

Tags: google-chrome, google-workspace-for-business, google-chrome-extensions

Sorry if this isn't the right place to ask this, but I can't find anywhere better.

I've set my users up with Google G-Suite so that they can use Chromebooks and Chrome Remote Desktop to work remotely while dealing with Corona.

I can access the marketplace on the Chromebooks logged in as the users, but I can not find a way to add CRD and Microsoft apps to the library or Computers. When I open marketplace on the laptops, I get a blank page that says "No results". In G-Suite admin, when try to add a service, or an app, the searches in the marketplace come up empty for both Microsoft and Chrome remote desktop.

Any idea where I'm going wrong?

[image: no results]

Comment: Try using the Chrome Web Store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome Remote Desktop is available in the Chrome Web Store not in the G Suite Marketplace.

Comment: The issue was that the only place I could add apps to the library for users is the marketplace. I was having an issue with users not being able to access the store which is why I was trying to add to the library. Once users had proper access to the store they could add from there.

Answer (score 1):

It appears it was an issue with allowing access to the store to users. There is a lag from when you allow access to when it propagates to all users. Once this propagation occurs, users can access all apps in the store as required.